# Intel XDK: editor doesn't recognize <script>

Tags: javascript, intel, intel-xdk

I've chosen a basic Intel XDK theme, but as soon as I try to paste some JavaScript into the `.js` page I receive the following message:

> Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'.(E030)

[image]

As you can see the first '<' is not interpreted. Why?

Comment: Because `<script>` is HTML and your file is called "app.js"?

Comment: The first '<' is wrong and the rest consists of consequential errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the script tag in a .js file. 
You only use the script tag when including the javascript  in a html file.

Comment: Rather than "not need to", you simply cannot. HTML and JavaScript are different languages and `<script>` is HTML, thus it isn't valid JavaScript. You'd get similar errors if you type SQL or PHP code.